# Is it possible to change the line of the link when referencing to a function with sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

When I use `` :func:`MyClass.myfunc` `` to reference an existing method of `MyClass` the link when you click on it send you to the line under the actual function declaration :

```
class MyClass()

  myfunc(input)                 # 1
    This function do something  # 2
```

The link send me to line 2. Is it possible to get the link to lead you to line 1?

Comment: That's not the behaviour I see, e.g. http://pythonhosted.org/aslack/aslack.html#aslack.slack_api.api_subclass_factory

Comment: ho... I think it might come from the bootstrap banner I have at the top of the window hiding the actual line referenced. See http://cerfacs.fr/antares/doc_1.8.2/src/api/zone.html#antares.Zone.cell_to_node

Comment: Looks like, yep; if you set the header to `display: none` the appropriate line is at the top of the page.

Comment: Indeed! I misdiagnosed my problem! Thank you for your help